# Automatic bulk insert / update with multiple variables

Tags: sql-server, triggers

Hej,

**Update**
Thank you guys for your answers and hints. I understand that my first attempt was wrong - so maybe the better approach is to describe my problem in words rather than trying a shitty trigger.

Table A is a list of all clients. For earch client exists multiple orders (next to other not needed information in that table):

| CLIENT | ORDER | OPTIONAL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | NO |
| A | 2 | YES |
| A | 3 | NO |
| B | 16818 | YES |
| B | 342 | YES |

I need to insert all OPTIONAL=NO orders into table B in an automatic bulk process. It is possible that an order is changed from OPTIONAL=NO to OPTIONAL=YES and therefore i need the solutions for not only inserts but updates.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Why does this need a cursor, it can be done in a single insert? What does the table called `Table` and aliased `R` contain and why are you cross joining it? Putting it another way: it seems to have `UniqueID`, perhaps it's just a single row, but you are inserting the same value on every run

Comment: If you want a `CURSOR` in a `TRIGGER` you have a design flaw. A `TRIGGER` should be as minimal as possible, and have the smallest amount of overhead possible. A `CURSOR` is the complete opposite to this. There are *very* few reasons to ever need a `CURSOR` in SQL Server anyway (I can probably list the valid reasons with one hand), however, if the process you want to implement truly requires a `CURSOR` (I doubt it), then it should be outside `TRIGGER` and you should have a scheduled task to run the process against the data that hasn't had it run against already.

Comment: *"I'm not able to create a trigger with a cursor which adds +1 to an unique ID"* This too, sounds like a design flaw. if you need to add 1 to a unique ID, then you should be using an `IDENTITY` or a `SEQUENCE`.

Comment: `FROM     INSERTED I, TABLE R` is not valid syntax. I can only pray that you are not attempting to use an old-style join (which is a [bad habit to kick](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) ) and accidentally producing a cross join.

Comment: I updated the original post - thank you very much for the first inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice for triggers:

1. Don't create them unless you have no other option.
2. It's usually best to separate insert and update triggers, sometimes they can be combined.
3. `NOCOUNT` stops spurious messages going back to the client, `XACT_ABORT` means any error automatically rolls back the transaction.
4. Check if there are any relevant rows, if not bail out early.
5. Also check if a column is present in the update statement using the `UPDATE()` function if relevant (this doesn't mean the row has actually changed)
6. In an `UPDATE` trigger, make sure you compare `inserted` and `deleted` rows for actual changes.
7. **Most important:** be aware that `inserted` and `deleted` **may contain multiple rows**.

```
CREATE TRIGGER Trg_TableA_OPTIONAL_ins
ON TableA
AFTER INSERT
AS

SET NOCOUNT, XACT_ABORT ON;

IF (NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM inserted WHERE OPTIONAL = 'NO'))
    RETURN;

INSERT TableB (CLIENT, [ORDER])
SELECT CLIENT, [ORDER]
    FROM inserted
    WHERE OPTIONAL = 'NO';

GO

CREATE TRIGGER Trg_TableA_OPTIONAL_upd
ON TableA
AFTER UPDATE
AS

SET NOCOUNT, XACT_ABORT ON;

IF (NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM inserted))
    RETURN;

INSERT TableB (CLIENT, [ORDER])
SELECT CLIENT, [ORDER]
FROM (
    SELECT CLIENT, [ORDER], OPTIONAL
        FROM inserted
        WHERE OPTIONAL = 'NO'
    EXCEPT
    SELECT CLIENT, [ORDER], OPTIONAL
        FROM deleted
) i
EXCEPT
SELECT CLIENT, [ORDER]
    FROM TableB;

DELETE FROM b
FROM TableB b
JOIN (
    SELECT CLIENT, [ORDER], OPTIONAL
        FROM inserted
        WHERE OPTIONAL = 'YES'
    EXCEPT
    SELECT CLIENT, [ORDER], OPTIONAL
        FROM deleted
) i
ON TableB.CLIENT = Source.CLIENT AND TABLEB.[ORDER] = Source.[ORDER];

GO
```